# Variable is not being set in use State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-table-v7

```
const DonorsTables = () =>{
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
  const [filteredcountries, setFilteredCountries] = useState([]);
 

  const getCountries = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get("https://restcountries.com/v2/all");
      setCountries = (response.data);
      setFilteredCountries = (response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      console.log("Not Data Found")
    }
  };
```

And in the console I am getting this no Data found..... Also, I am getting the warning that setCountries is defined but its value is never used. And an Error of assignment to a constant variable error in  setCountries = (response.data);

I want to diplay the list of countries on my screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setCountries` and `setFilteredCountries` are functions

```
  setCountries(response.data);
  setFilteredCountries(response.data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const DonorsTables = () =>{
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
  const [filteredcountries, setFilteredCountries] = useState([]);
 

  const getCountries = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get("https://restcountries.com/v2/all");
      setCountries(response.data);
      setFilteredCountries(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      console.log("Not Data Found")
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you update state in React.

`useState` returns a state variable and a state update function. In your code you are assigning `response.data` to the state update function `setCountries = (response.data)` which is simply incorrect.

To update the state you need to call the state update function passing as argument your new state

```
  setCountries(response.data);
  setFilteredCountries(response.data);
```

by writing `setCountries(response.data)` you can imagine it ***as*** if you write `countries=response.data` . React actually does this *internally* for you when you call `setCountries(response.data)`, among other things

Answer (score 0):

When you create new state using hook useState, you create state and function that change state, and if you want change value you should use setState as function.

Try:

setCountries(response.data);
setFiltredCounties(response.data);